# How to enforce calling abstract class constructor when using non positional parameters?

Tags: dart

I have following code:

```dart
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class Dependency {}

abstract class A1 {
  final Dependency dependency;

  A1({ @required this.dependency }); // non positional parameter with @required (does not work)
}

abstract class A2 {
  final Dependency dependency;

  A2(this.dependency); // positional parameter (works causing analyzer error)
}

class B1 extends A1 {} // No error / warning
class B2 extends A2 {} // analyzer error: The superclass 'A2' doesn't have a zero argument constructor.
```

Is there any way to force analyzer to show error in case `class B1 extends A1 {}`?

Comment: When the `required` tag becomes an official part of the Dart language, maybe this will become a feature. Until then, `required` just adds an IDE warning when the parameter is omitted but doesn't actually enforce compile-time safety. So no, there's no way to do this (yet).

Comment: @Abion47 Think you meant to add an @ on that second `required`. :)

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Not really.

Comment: @Abion47 `required` is not a warning, while the annotation `@required` is. `required` should enforce compile-time safety. This can already be done with null-safety enabled.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore The `required` keyword is still an experimental feature as part of the NNBD update and thus not an official part of the Dart language yet as far as the community at large is concerned. And at any rate, It's clear which `required` I was referring to based on the context of both the question and the whole of my comment. This is pedantism, pure and simple.

Comment: @Abion47 Not sure what you mean. It would be far clearer to use `@required` if that's what you meant. If you really meant to say `required` then I'm confused.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Then you are confused. I don't know what to tell you. The context clearly spelled out that I was referring to the `required` annotation and not the as-of-yet-unreleased keyword. You really are making a much bigger deal out of this than necessary.

Comment: @Abion47 I'm sorry for offending you in any way. I just thought I would point that out for clarity so that you could edit it while you still could and help others better. I'm just thinking that people like myself with less knowledge of dart may get confused by reading  it by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done with the stable version of dart at the moment. `@required` is just an annotation and not really a part of the language so the analyzer can't pick up on the problem you pose. However, with null-safety enabled in beta and higher channels, this is possible with the `required` keyword.

You can try this by enabling null-safety and changing `@required` to `required`.

You could try this easily in dartpad

or

switch to a beta or higher channel and change your dart sdk version constraints to have a minimum of 2.12.0-0.

```
sdk: ">=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0"
```